# thmtools note spacing fix

Tags: thmtools

I've run into some spacing problems when attempting to create my own theorem styles using `thmtools`. What I want can be condensed into the following points:

- Theorem name should be in the margin and spaced relative to the text body by a `\marginparsep` width.
- The theorem note should be in the text body and have a space following it.
- If no note is used, the following text should still be aligned to the text body with no indents.

I realize that I can create a separate theorem style for when I want to use a note and when I don't, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require that if possible.

Here's an example that illustrates the problem I've ran into:
[image]

And here's the code for the above example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\bfseries\scshape,
notefont=\normalfont, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
headpunct={},
postheadspace={0pt},
headformat={%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\NAME\ \NUMBER\hspace{\marginparsep}}\NOTE%
}
]{problemA}

\declaretheorem[
name=Theorem,
style=problemA
]{theoremA}

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\bfseries\scshape,
notefont=\normalfont, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
headpunct={},
postheadspace={0pt},
preheadhook=\renewcommand\thmt@space{}, % Removes \NOTE spacing
headformat={%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\NAME\ \NUMBER\hspace{\marginparsep}}\NOTE%
}
]{problemB}

\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\bfseries,
notefont=\normalfont, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
headpunct={},
postheadspace={5pt},
preheadhook=\renewcommand\thmt@space{}, % Removes \NOTE spacing
headformat={%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\NAME\ \NUMBER\hspace{\marginparsep}}\NOTE%
}
]{problemC}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[
name=Theorem,
style=problemB
]{theoremB}

\declaretheorem[
name=Theorem,
style=problemC
]{theoremC}

\begin{document}

\begin{theoremA}[Test]
  Here we get undesired space around \texttt{\textbackslash NOTE}.
\end{theoremA}

\begin{theoremB}[Test]
  Now we eliminated the undesired space.
\end{theoremB}

\begin{theoremB}
  Also works without the note.
\end{theoremB}

\begin{theoremC}[Test]
  Also works with \texttt{postheadspace}.

\end{theoremC}

\begin{theoremC}
  But now we get an indent when we don't use a note.
\end{theoremC}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `notebraces` are embedded in `\NOTE` you can add the desired space *after* the closing brace and it will be called only if there is a note:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\makeatletter

\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\bfseries,
notefont=\normalfont, notebraces={(}{)\hspace{5pt}},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
headpunct={},
postheadspace={0pt},
preheadhook=\renewcommand\thmt@space{}, % Removes \NOTE spacing
headformat={%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\NAME\ \NUMBER\hspace{\marginparsep}}\NOTE%
}
]{fivept}

\usepackage{xspace}
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\bfseries,
notefont=\normalfont, notebraces={(}{) },
bodyfont=\normalfont,
headpunct={},
postheadspace={0pt},
preheadhook=\renewcommand\thmt@space{}, % Removes \NOTE spacing
headformat={%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\NAME\ \NUMBER\hspace{\marginparsep}}\NOTE%
}
]{singlespace}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[
name=Theorem,
style=fivept
]{fivept}

\declaretheorem[
name=Theorem,
style=singlespace
]{singlespace}

\begin{document}

\begin{fivept}[Test]
  \verb|notebraces={(}{)\hspace{5pt}}|
\end{fivept}

\begin{fivept}
  No undesired space.
\end{fivept}

\begin{singlespace}[Test]
  \verb|notebraces={(}{) }|
\end{singlespace}

\begin{singlespace}
  Also no undesired space.
\end{singlespace}

\end{document}
```

[image]